# Loop is missing values while iterating through JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, ecmascript-6

I want to iterate through an array of objects and put all 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> values in an array in order from top to bottom.

The returned array was supposed to contain 31 elements but my solution written below returns `array.length == 29`. I can't find where the loop is losing values.

```js
let userTree = [{
  "username": "USER1",
  "income": 1000,
  "st1": {
    "username": "USER2",
    "income": 2000,
    "st1": {
      "username": "USER4",
      "income": 4564560,
      "st1": '',
      "nd2": {
        "username": "USER7",
        "income": 4564560,
        "st1": {
          "username": "USER10",
          "income": 4564560,
          "st1": '',
          "nd2": ''
        },
        "nd2": {
          "username": "USER11",
          "income": 4564560,
          "st1": '',
          "nd2": ''
        }
      }
    },
    "nd2": ''
  },
  "nd2": {
    "username": "USER3",
    "income": 2001,
    "st1": {
      "username": "USER5",
      "income": 40,
      "st1": '',
      "nd2": ''
    },
    "nd2": {
      "username": "USER6",
      "income": 4564560,
      "st1": {
        "username": "USER8",
        "income": 40,
        "st1": '',
        "nd2": {
          "username": "USER12",
          "income": 40,
          "st1": '',
          "nd2": ''
        }
      },
      "nd2": {
        "username": "USER9",
        "income": 40,
        "st1": {
          "username": "USER13",
          "income": 40,
          "st1": '',
          "nd2": ''
        },
        "nd2": {
          "username": "USER14",
          "income": 40,
          "st1": '',
          "nd2": ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}];


let userArray = [userTree[0]];
let counter = 1;
let rowArray = [];
let counterArr = [];
let usersRow = '';
let rowHTML = '';
let treeRow = '';

const getUsers = (users = {}) => {
  Object.entries(users).forEach(user => {
    let key = user[0];
    let value = user[1];
    if (typeof value == 'object') {
      userArray.push(value);
    } else if (value == '') {
      userArray.push(value);
    }
  });
};


const getSubUsers = (subUser = {}) => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= userArray.length; i++) {
    let lastUser = userArray[i];
    getUsers(lastUser);
  }
};

getSubUsers(userArray);

console.log(userArray.length);

console.log(userArray);
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Step through it, even with print debugging, and question each step until you know it is correct before moving onto the next step. Show your research. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Where did you find 31 occurrences? There is 29, isn't it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5p9ymqa1/ made another implementation. I thought that there should be 31 as you wrote. But got 29 by my algorithm and then counted all the values without code just looking at your json. And there is no 31 here

Comment: That is a JS object literal.  JSON is *always* a string.

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag. What you have there is not JSON.